# CSS Grid Vertical Divider Between Two Items

Tags: html, flexbox, css-grid

I'm creating a grid layout using **CSS Grid**. I want to make the entire grid items have **right divider** before the next item, but **except** the last item in the same row **dynamically** depends on the grid condition.

Here's what I've tried, the Item 3's divider **should not** exist because it's the last item in row 1, as well as Item 5.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

html, body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.grid {
  width: 25em;
  padding: .5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(6em, 1fr));
  grid-gap: .5em;
  border: 1px dashed palevioletred;
}

.grid > .item {
  padding: 2em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid > .item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: .025em;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: What happens if there's only one element in the last row ?

Comment: It won't have the divider, because there's no item anymore next to it

Answer (score 2):

Given that your columns number is fixed at 3

You can do this with the border of the element, But I used the pseudo-element instead as to no mess with it's width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.grid {
  width: 25em;
  padding: .5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(6em, 1fr));
  grid-gap: .5em;
  border: 1px dashed palevioletred;
}

.grid>.item {
  padding: 2em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Added */
.grid>.item:nth-child(3n+2):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -.5em;
  right: -.5em;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: .5em solid red;
  border-right: .5em solid red;
}

.grid>.item:last-child:before {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, does it work for dynamic column numbers too?

Comment: @JustinusHermawan No, the provided code only works for 3 columns layout, if it's probably not possible for a dynamic number of columns, I'll have to do more testing

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 .grid > .item:not(:nth-child(3n))::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: .025em;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

html, body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.grid {
  width: 25em;
  padding: .5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(6em, 1fr));
  grid-gap: .5em;
  border: 1px dashed palevioletred;
}

.grid > .item {
  padding: 2em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid > .item:not(:nth-child(3n))::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: .025em;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But, I need to make the whole items wrap automatically in a single row

Comment: And for the Item 5, it should not exist too because it's the last one in that row